# Build error cordova application, "Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-file"

Tags: android, cordova, http-status-code-404, cordova-plugins

I'm tryng to build my cordova application, but from 2015, 3rd April, building gave me this error:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-media-capture" for android
Running command: C:\wamp\www\HTML5Application\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat 
Command finished with error code 0: C:\wamp\www\HTML5Application\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat 
Dependencies detected, iterating through them...
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" not fetched, retrieving then installing.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file" via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file
npm http 404 http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-media-capture':Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-file
at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:268:14)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:148:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:876:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-file
at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:268:14)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:148:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:876:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoniof\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
C:\wamp\www\HTML5Application\nbproject\build.xml:235: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 48 seconds)
```

It seems that the error does not depend on me, because cmd http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file returns

> {"error":"not_found","reason":"document not found"}

is there a way to report the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use `org.apache.cordova.file` until further notice. That is still the id used in the plugin registry: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file
That new plugin id is on the dev branch and is unreleased. If you need to actually install the dev version right now, do a:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git`

Source: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8806

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the plugin manually in your console:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

Note that you have to be in the base directory of your project.

Comment: Hi Sven and thank you for your response. I omitted that I ran the build through Netbeans 8.0.2. However, by running your command, I received other errors, so I decided to remove the Android platform, and re-add and build it again. Of course, running these on command line rather than through netbeans. Now everything works. I hope that this information will be useful to someone else.
Thank you